# HMM with some known inputs

Tags: multinomial-distribution, hidden-markov-model, baum-welch

I am trying to solve a problem using HMM where the observations Yt are the result of both known and hidden parameters, but unfortunately, I am not sure how to combine the known and hidden parameters for both training and evaluation of the HMM. I have looked at general Bayesian networks for a hint but am not finding what I need. I am wondering if there is a standard approach for doing this and if anyone could point me in the right general direction?

Comment: what do u mean by known parameters ?

Comment: In addition to the hidden states, there are input values that are known as well as the output. To improve the HMM effectiveness, the idea is to use both the known inputs and the observed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) use known inputs a external variables to HMM( Heterogeneous HMM)
1) Can't u ensemble HMM ( for hidden state) with some other also algo for known parameters?
2) Output of HMM can be taken with other known parameters and then you can try some algo based on your problem.

Comment: Any suggestion for the other algorithm and analysis process that could be used? I am not sure what you are suggesting just yet.

Comment: if those are known then, you can use heterogeneous HMM where these known values can be passed as external variables. In this scenario, you transition probabilities would be function of known inputs( external variables).

Comment: No need to ensemble with other algos!!

Comment: As an aside, do you happen to know if heterogeneous HMMs are the same as Input-Output HMMs? Seeing them come up at the same time but don't know the difference.

Comment: i think they r different..I don't have any knowledge of Input/Output HMM .:)